# rails delayed_job with dynamic SMTP (settings)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, delayed-job

Rails 4, Ruby 2, delayed_job 4.0.2
Can I set dynamic SMTP settings?
For example, I need set user_name and password, where I should add that attributes?
My code:

```
  class Email < Struct.new(:user_id, :attr)
    def save
      user = User.find(user_id)
      ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings
        .merge!({ user_name: attr['serverEmail'], password: attr['serverPass'] })
      ReportMailer.delay.send_report(user, attr)
    end
  end
```

As you can see, I added `.merge!(...needed attributes...)`, but that is not working!
As for me `delay_job` working only if I add all attributes to `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {...}`

, but I need dynamic settings
**Need help! Thanks!** 
P.S. 
Copy at [github](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/680)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got ansver from albus522 (delay_job developer):
"You will have to change the settings in the send_report mailer method. Otherwise DJ has no idea it was changed". 
So, I've move

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings
    .merge!({ user_name: attr['serverEmail'], password: attr['serverPass'] })
```

from

```
class Email
```

to

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
#send_report method
```

and all working!
**Thanks!**